# What does schema.org/person markup influence?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

What kind of snippet does implementing Schema.org/person markup help generate? Will all the details in the markup end up in the SERP snippet?

Answer (score 3):

Rich snippets are given under certain conditions, schema **isn't** one of this conditions and also it doesn't have any direct impact on your SEO but that doesn't mean that it has no influence, the fact that it is not boosting your site now doesn't mean it won't happen in the near feature, schema has good chances to get in google algorithm among with SSL certificates, because schema is enjoying fantastic support, and it is a better user experience.

So basically it won't help about your snippet in SERPs but that doesn't mean it won't help you at other ranking factors, **and there is absolutely no reason to not use schema**.

This is my opinion I might be missing something!

Answer (score -1):

schema.org is for better user experience as snippets results in SERP's help user to get more information about a website. I will say this will indirectly help SEO but not directly